# Scope issue with callback in Validate function in Iron Validate Behavior

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.*

In a parent element, I am using `Polymer.IronValidatableBehavior`.

I am having a scope issue with the callback function arg `this.setInvalidStates`. In the child element `birthdate`, the callback shows `undefined`  in the function `checkIfDateHasValue: function(setInvalidStates) { }`

Is there a way to fix the scope so I can pass in the function `this.setInvalidStates` as a callback?

parent element:

```
  setInvalidStates: function() {
    ...
  },

  validate: function() {
    if (this.required) {
      return this.$.birthdate
        .checkIfDateHasValue(this.setInvalidStates).bind(this);
    }

    return true;
  },
```

birthdate child element:

```
checkIfDateHasValue: function(setInvalidStates) {
  if (!this.$.datePicker.value) {
    setInvalidStates(true);

    this.errorMessage = '*birth date required under certain '
      + 'choices';

    return false;
  }

  return true;
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you should use `bind`, but applied to the argument:

```
.checkIfDateHasValue(this.setInvalidStates.bind(this))
```

You don't need the original, outer `bind(this)`, as `checkIfDateHasValue` does not return a function, but a boolean. Also `validate` should not return a function, but a boolean, so `bind` does not make sense then (at the original place).

Comment: That indicates that your `this` object does not have a `setInvalidStates` method. How do you call `validate`? Can you show fiddle that actually produces the problem?

Comment: this worked....thanks. my issue was also because of a underscore in function name I did not realize.